# FT232RL TX/RX Direction

Tags: serial, uart, ftdi

I want to basically embed an [FTDI cable](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12731) in my board to avoid confusion with the RX/TX pins, wrong cable, etc.

I really want to make sure I choose the direction correctly though.  I have `UART_TXO` OUT of the micro and `UART_RXI` INTO the micro.  How should these be connected to the FT232R?  I'm having trouble really nailing down the direction of each pin.  Currently, I have:

[image]

Also the FT232R requires no programming, correct?

Comment: As long as your UART_RXI is the microcontroller's RXI input (driven by FTDI TXD output), and your UART_TXO is the microcontroller's TXO output (which drives the FTDI RXD input), you should be good.
FT232R will look like a standard USB serial port, your software will need to configure the baud rate to match the baud rate used by your firmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the RX pin of one device should be connected to the TX pin of the other, and vice versa. The R in RX stands for receive, and the T in TX stands for transmit.

Also, to the best of my understanding, the FTDI serial chips do not need to be programmed, plug and play so to speak.